# "Monkey Test" app is always downloaded every time I am online

Tags: applications, malware

My phone keeps downloading apps like "Cash Yourself", "Monkey Test" and many more.

I have tried to stop and clear data, but every time I am online they were download again.

How can I stop this?

Comment: According to [this source](http://forums.androidcentral.com/general-help-how/365217-random-apps-keep-installing-themselves.html) it may help to change your Google password. Don't know if that is correct though.

Answer (score -1):

Open the Play Store. Navigate to "My Apps". Untick the box for "Update applications automatically". Then, try to clear data once again.

Comment: Hi Zeniteox is that in setting the untick box i cannot find it

Answer (score -2):

Open Play store, go to settings, then go to Auto-Update Option and select the desired option